# No SOAPAction header error with VBA in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, soap, wsdl

I am trying to retrieve some information via a SOAP request in VBA in Excel 2010. I haven't used this before but I did do some searching around and adapted different codes to come up with something I think should work but I keep getting stuck with the same error (no SOAPAction header). I tried the WSDL in SoapUI and it works so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The WSDL I am making the request to:

```
http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL
```

The Error I keep getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
   <faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">SERVAP9</ns2:hostname>
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The VBA code I am using:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SOAP()
'Set and instantiate our working objects
    Dim Req As Object
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim Resp As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Resp = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    Req.Open "Post", "http://www.banxico.org.mx/DgieWSWeb/DgieWS?WSDL", False


'Create SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
     sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ws=""http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx"">"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Header/>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Body>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "    <ws:tiposDeCambioBanxico soapenv:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""/>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  </soapenv:Body>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"

' Send SOAP Request
    Req.send (sEnv)

' Display results in MessageBox
    'MsgBox Req.responseText

    Resp.LoadXML Req.responseText
    Debug.Print Req.responseText

  'clean up code
    Set Req = Nothing
    Set Resp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this block:

```
'Create SOAP envelope for submission to the Web Service
     sEnv = sEnv & "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ws=""http://ws.dgie.banxico.org.mx"">"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Header/>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  <soapenv:Body>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "    <ws:tiposDeCambioBanxico soapenv:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/""/>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "  </soapenv:Body>"
     sEnv = sEnv & "</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

You should take out the `<soapenv:Header/>` or add a corresponding `</soapenv:header>` after the line `</soapenv:Body>`.

Comment: I still get the same error after trying both suggestions.